# XSLT - Removing CDATA without disabling output escaping

Tags: xslt-2.0, cdata

Having a bit of an issue with CDATA. For my current project, I had to convert a number of HTML elements into CDATA in order to be imported to a test case management system via XML. I am now tasked with exporting that data and translating it into DITA. The following is an excerpt from the data I am working with that I think provides enough context:

```
<tr:testopia><tr:testplan><tr:testcase>
    <tr:text version="1">
        <tr:author>bugzilla</tr:author>
        <tr:action><![CDATA[<ol xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
              <li>
                 <p xmlns:xh="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" 
                    xmlns:cln="http://clean/"     class="Table">Refer to 
                    <span style="color:red">CHM795_Workflow_DITA_Test_plan.doc
                    </span>
                 </p>
              </li>
           </ol>]]></tr:action>
        <tr:expected_result><![CDATA[<ol xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
              <li>
                 <p xmlns:xh="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" 
                    xmlns:cln="http://clean/"     
                    class="Table">All requirements are met & example example</p>
              </li>
           </ol>]]></tr:expected_result>
        <tr:setup><![CDATA[]]></tr:setup>
        <tr:breakdown><![CDATA[]]></tr:breakdown>
     </tr:text>
</tr:testcase></tr:testplan></tr:testopia>
```

To do this, I need to get the elements previously kept in CDATA out again, and I've found from a small amount of research that a line such as the following will achieve this:

```
<xsl:template match="tr:text">
        <prerequisites>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="tr:setup"/>
        </prerequisites>
        <postrequisites>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="tr:breakdown"/>
        </postrequisites>
    <process>
        <actions>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="tr:action"/>
        </actions>
        <results>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="tr:expected_result"/>
        </results>
    </process>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="text()">
    <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(.)" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
</xsl:template>
```

This will provide me with the following:

```
<case>
  <prerequisites/>
  <postrequisites/>
  <process>
     <actions><ol xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> <li> <p xmlns:xh="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:cln="http://clean/" class="Table">Perform <span style="color:red">ASM Test Document.docx</span> </p> </li> </ol></actions>
     <results><ol xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> <li> <p xmlns:xh="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:cln="http://clean/" class="Table">Test plan successfully completed</p> </li> </ol></results>
  </process>
```

The issue I currently face is this: disabling output escaping gets me the format I need, translation has worked fine and the DITA file validates. However, in some of these test cases, the content of the HTML elements sometimes contain characters such as `&`. When I try to translate these cases into their final form after this stage, I receive an error like the following when running with SAXON:

```
Error reported by XML parser: The entity name must immediately follow 
the '&' in the entity reference.
```

Is there a way I can keep the internal text of the nodes in their current "harmless" state and still wrap it in the nodes also held in CDATA? Could probably phrase that better, but the words aren't coming to mind.

Comment: Isn't it odd that Stack Overflow seems to edit out greetings at the start of questions?

Comment: Please post minimal but complete samples of XML input and XSLT code allowing us to reproduce the problem. If Saxon tells you `Error reported by XML parser` then the XML input or the stylesheet code is not well-formed XML and that error occurs before any XSLT code is being run. Or are you trying to feed the result of `<xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(.)" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>` to an XML parser

Comment: I should clarify - the error occurs when attempting to translate the output of this translation. This first translation is technically successful, but incorrect, as the desired elements are pulled out, but their text contents are causing problems that text should not. I'll add more context in just a moment, but I'm wary of flooding the page.

Comment: Well if you use disable-output-escaping then you can of course produce something with XSLT that is not well-formed XML. If you then feed mal-formed XML to an XML parser you get a parsing error. So you will have to decide what you want to produce and which tools you want to use. If you want to produce mal-formed output then you can't feed it to an XML parser (and an XSLT processor normally uses an XML parser on its input to build the tree it operates on). I think Saxon allows you to plugin other parses like TagSoup but you will need to configure that.

Comment: The issue is, I do not want to produce malformed output. I am aware that disabling output escaping is producing the malformed XML, and so I am looking for an alternative approach (see the title of the post) that will let me extract the node structure from the CDATA, while still keeping the text of those nodes as just that. Sorry if I sound a bit snarky, I appreciate the help.

Comment: Consider to post a sample of the output you want, in particular if the input has e.g. `<![CDATA[All requirements are met & example example]]>` and you do your transformation. Saxon's commercial versions have http://www.saxonica.com/documentation/index.html#!functions/saxon/parse-html so you could try to parse the escaped broken XHTML as HTML tag soup instead and then process the tree with normal templates.